# How can I change the Page in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am on FirstPage and want to change to SecondPage by calling

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new SecondPage());
```

But I always get an Exception. How do I navigate?

Answer (score 3):

PushAsync is for use in a NavigationPage which handles Navigation for you. For this create your MainPage in your App class like this:

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new FirstPage());
```

Then you can use PushAsync.

If you don't want to use a NavigationPage for certain reasons, you should use

```
await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new SecondPage());
```

With this you have something like a two-dimensional navigation stack.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your First Page as your main page.

```
MainPage=new NavigationPage(new FirstPage());
```

And from the FirstPage you can go to the second page using a click event

```
btnTest.Clicked += async (sender, e) =>
{
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new SecondPage());
};
```